# Finding an alternate to a for-loop for for implementing logic in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df1

                      Rule 1           Rule 2         Rule 3         Rule 4         Rule 5         Rule 6
0                   A == 'ABC'         
1                   B == 1234          
2                   C== 'ABC123'     C== 'XYZ123'     
3                   D>= 20150101     D<= 20990101                                    
4                   O== '12.34.56'   O== '24.65.12'   
5                   W>= -1.00        W<= 3000                                    
6                   P== '589qs'
```

I am implementing the for-loop on the dataframe:

```py
for i in range(len(df1.index)):
 answer = eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 1']) or eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 2']) or eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 3']) or eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 4']) or eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 5']) or eval(df1.loc[i, 'Rule 6'])
 answer_list.append(answer)
```

As you can see, I am using the `eval()` function that evaluates the conditions given in the dataframe and stores the boolean output in a variable. The relation between the columns is supposed to be the 'OR' function and the relation between the rows **can be other than 'OR'**

The problem is that the dataframe is too big to implement a for-loop since it takes too much time.
I am looking to **use the `apply()` function instead of a for-loop** to reduce the run-time but cannot seem to understand how to do it.

What I've tried:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: answer_list.append((eval(x.values))), axis = 1)
```

Obviously, it gives an error because in this case, `x.values` gives the whole row as a series.
How can I replace the for-loop with the apply() function in this case? Or can something else be implemented?

Comment: what kind of variables are A, B, C, etc. in your Dataframe?

Comment: They are defined variables in the script. Their values are updated from another dataframe.

Comment: did you try `answer_list = df1.apply(lambda x: eval(x.values), axis=1).tolist()` ? or something similar where eval will evaluate all the rules of the row. Something like: `answer_list = df1.apply(lambda x: eval(x["Rule 1"]) or eval(x["Rule 2"]), axis=1).tolist()`

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, ```x.values``` is a series and ```eval()``` doesn't accept it as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your own eval function and apply it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['1 == 1', '3 == 3'], ['2 == 2', '4 == 4'], ['1 > 2', '5 > 6']], columns=['Rule1', 'Rule2'])

def my_eval_func(*args):
    answer = False
    for arg in args[0]:
        answer = answer or eval(arg)
    return answer

df['answer'] = df.apply(my_eval_func, axis=1)
print(df.head)


>    Rule1   Rule2  answer
>0  1 == 1  3 == 3    True
>1  2 == 2  4 == 4    True
>2   1 > 2   5 > 6   False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply and evaluate by row, using something like this:

```
answer_list = df.apply(lambda x: sum(eval(x[c]) for c in df.columns) > 0, axis=1).tolist()
```

You can access the series rows like a dictionnary (`x` in the code), so you can either create your own function to make your code more readable, or create a lambda like i did in this example.

Appending to a list in an apply does work, like printing in a list as comprehension, but i find it a bit ugly. Especially when you can obtain the result directly without appending (since apply probably loops and appends).

---